# Using 'authorize-security-group-ingress --ip-permissions' for multiple rules while also setting tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm scripting some security group handling for our AWS EC2 instances.  Given a freshly-created security group, we can add rules to it like this.  (Yes, all the port and address numbers are gibberish for SO examples, it's fine.)  Because we're adding more than one rule, we have to use the `--ip-permissions` parameter rather than all of the individual `--port`, `--cidr`, and so on.

```bash
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-12345 --ip-permissions \
   'IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=1,ToPort=1,IpRanges=[{CidrIp="1.2.3.4/16",Description="example 1"}]' \
   'IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=2,ToPort=2,IpRanges=[{CidrIp="5.6.7.8/16",Description="example 2"}]' \
   'IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=3,ToPort=3,IpRanges=[{CidrIp="9.10.11.12/16",Description="example 3"}]'
```

That works fine.  However, I'd like to also use a Name tag in each rule to make the web-based "console" a little easier to read.  The syntax with `authorize-security-group-ingress` and other commands is:

```bash
aws ...same-command-as-above... --tag-specifications \
   'ResourceType=security-group-rule,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=Rule Name Goes Here}]'
```

and that also works fine, **but** applies the same Name tag to every created rule.  I'm trying to get a different Name applied for each rule, but cannot work out the syntax.

My initial attempt was to repeat the tag-spec clause for each rule, in the same order:

```bash
aws ...same-command-as-above... --tag-specifications \
   'ResourceType=security-group-rule,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=Rule 1 Name}]' \
   'ResourceType=security-group-rule,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=Rule 2 Name}]' \
   'ResourceType=security-group-rule,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=Rule 3 Name}]'
```

but that gives the error

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress
operation: The same resource type may not be specified more than once in tag specifications
```

Given that multiple Name tags are each going to be using the same resource type (the "security-group-rule" part), I'm not certain what else to try here.

Am I just out of luck?  I was hoping to do all the rule creations in a single call.

Annoyingly, there doesn't seem to be a way to modify a rule's tags after creation.  There is a `modify-security-group-rules` subcommand, but none of its docs mention anything about editing the tags in any way, at least not with aws-cli 2.11.19.  Which makes me think that despite the ability of `--ip-permissions` to take multiple rules, we can actually only give one at a time if we're also passing `--tag-specifications`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to do multiple rule creations in a single call, while assigning different tags to each rule. You would have to put your code in a script, and have that script loop over each rule you need to create, making the API call one by one.

I think you might be able to use [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/tag-resources.html) `tag-resources` command to tag your security group rules after they are created.

Comment: I had tentatively come to the same conclusion (no way to do that), but it's good to have independent confirmation, thank you!  The script runs in a one-rule-per-iteration loop now; it's slower but has no problems.

Comment: I'll definitely take a close look at that `tag-resources` CLI; that offers hope!  It's annoying that CFN templates can't specify tags in individual rules ("Encountered unsupported property Tags"),  regardless of whether the rules are in an `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` nested ingress/egress list, or in a separate `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup{In,E}gress` resource.  I had briefly thought about trying to do the work in the associated `UserData` script, but there's no way to get the ID code of the security group _rule_ using `Ref` at all, and none of the resources can be referred to from `UserData`.

Comment: Honestly I never mess with tags on security group rules. I always use the `description` field instead.

Comment: Oh, we use Description as well, it's just a pain in the ass to see it on the web console.  :-)  And we'd been thinking to use some other tags on SG rules, so getting "Name" working will be useful for that effort.  (Annoyingly, `describe-security-groups` has useful `--filters` for matching rules but doesn't show the resulting rule ID, while `describe-security-group-rules` knows the rule ID but has worthless filters, requiring client-side looping.  Ah well, eventually... :-)